# convert requests.models.Response to Django HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, python-requests, response, httpresponse

In my Django project, I need to get/post some data to a third-party url in my view, and redirect to the web page it provides. For example, I can simply do something like

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
            'order_id': 88888,
            'subject': 'haha',
            'rn_check': 'F',
            'app_pay': 'T',
        }
        url = 'http://some-third-party-api-url?order_id=88888&subject=haha&...'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

However I want to use this third-party api as a wrapped SDK , like

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from sucre.alipay_sdk.base import Alipay
        from sucre.alipay_sdk import alipay_config
        from django.http import HttpResponse
        alipay = Alipay(alipay_config)
        data = {
            'order_id': 88888,
            'subject': 'haha',
            'rn_check': 'F',
            'app_pay': 'T',
        }
        '''alipay api is wrapped in a sdk'''
        '''and return a requests.models.Response instance'''
        result = alipay.api('pay', data)
        return HttpResponse(result)
```

and the api code:

```
def api(self, service, data):
    ''' some logics here '''
    import requests
    response = requests.get(url, data=data)
    return response
```

But seems HttpResponse(result) is not the correct way to convert a requests.models.Response instance to HttpResponse... The layout is bad, and some more encoding issues, etc...Is there a correct way to convert requests response to Django HttpResponse?

---

Updates:

HttpResponse(result) worked, but some css of the page was lost. This might be related with using requests.

Comment: Take a look at [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: Thank @Olian04 for the advice. (As this was the first time I used stackoverflow to ask a question) However the completed code was too long and not really about the question itself - conversion from response of requests to HttpResponse..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should works:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests

requests_response = requests.get('/some-url/')

django_response = HttpResponse(
    content=requests_response.content,
    status=requests_response.status_code,
    content_type=requests_response.headers['Content-Type']
)

return django_response
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To add to Brian Loughnane's answer: when I tried the solution:

```
for k, v in requests_response.headers.items():
    django_response[k] = v
```

I got an error from django: AssertionError: Hop-by-hop headers not allowed

I don't know if it's the best solution but I "fixed" it by removing the offending headers.

```
from wsgiref.util import is_hop_by_hop

for k, v in requests_response.headers.items():
    if not is_hop_by_hop(k):
        django_response[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

`requests.models.Response` class which,has json() method (according to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=json#requests.Response.json)) that deserializes the JSON response into a Python object using json.loads(). Try to print following and you can access whatever you are looking for.

```
print yourResponse.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to paivatulio's answer, you can forward the headers like so:

```
for k, v in requests_response.headers.items():
  django_response[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation to post comments, but this might help:

If you came searching for Django Rest Framework way of doing this, we can modify @paivatulio’s answer like this:

```
import requests
from rest_framework.response import Response

requests_response = requests.get('/some-url/')

def covert_to_drf_response(response):
    drf_response = Response(
        data=requests_response.json(), 
      status=requests_response.status_code), 
    )

    return drf_response

drf_response = convert_to_drf_response(requests_response)
```

This might also be helpful if you prefer to use DRF’s Response over HttpResponse for the reasons stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192986/difference-between-response-and-httpresponse-django)

You can also set your content_type as @paivatulio did.