# difference between Response and HttpResponse django

Tags: django

What is the difference between Response and HttpResponse in django? I am a bit confused.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
Return Respose
```

and

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse
```

Comment: You should show your import paths and which Django version, as I don't believe `Response` is in Django any longer - at least as of 1.11+ (if it was before, I am not sure).

Comment: i still use Response in django 1.11

requirements.txt 

Django==1.11.5
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
django-filter==1.0.4
djangorestframework==3.6.4
djangorestframework-filters==0.10.1
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0

Answer (score 2):

drf's `Response` subclasses django's `SimpleTemplateResponse`. `SimpleTemplateResponse` subclasses `HttpResponse`. That is to say, `Response` has more features than `HttpResponse`.

1. `Response` provides a [Web browsable API](https://restframework.herokuapp.com/), a huge usability win for developers.
2. `Response` can handle native Python primitives such as `dict`, `list` and `str`. However, `HTTPResponse` only supports `str`, if you return is `dict` or `list`, `HTTPResponse` will convert them. And you will find the converted `str` is not what you want.

Here is the difference what I have learned so far.

Answer (score 1):

HttpResponse->SimpleTemplateResponse->Response

code:

```
"""
The Response class in REST framework is similar to HTTPResponse, except that
it is initialized with unrendered data, instead of a pre-rendered string.

The appropriate renderer is called during Django's template response rendering.
"""
class Response(SimpleTemplateResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that allows its data to be rendered into
    arbitrary media types.
    """
```

Answer (score -4):

You shouldn't use libraries without reading their documentation.

Response is from Django Rest Framework, not Django, and is [fully documented](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#requests) there.

Comment: This might be a more appropriate link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/